# Paths to differents files in one view - Joomla

Tags: php, templates, view, joomla, path

I'm trying to put a link in a component's view file (default.php) to another file in the same view (default_formulaire.php) as you can see below:

[image]

But I really don't know how to access it in PHP.
I know that the `default.php` file's url is: 
`index.php?option=com_multicontact&view=reclamation`
but I don't know that of `default_formulaire.php`.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to any view in Joomla is the following:

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&view=viewname&layout=layoutname
```

However, if the `layout` is omitted from the URL, then it is assumed that it is set to `default`. So, the following URL:

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&view=viewname
```

Will mean that the layout is `default`, which means that the `default.php` file will be loaded.

So, in your situation, the URL to load the `default_formulaire` layout will be:

```
index.php?option=com_multicontact&view=reclamation&view=default_formulaire
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access a different layout in joomla then you need to add a layout value in joomla url like `index.php?option=com_multicontact&view=reclamation&layout=default_formulaire`